# How can we batch convert chess move files of .pgn file format to .bin file format?

Tags: files, format, text, convert, batch

**Prologue:**  A `.pgn` format is type of text file format used for recording Chess moves with other information like date, event, score, opening, engine evaluation, variations, depth etc. This file format can be easily saved as `.txt` format also and can be opened with notepad++, etc. When this same `.pgn` file is converted to machine readable binary format (`.bin` format) using `create.bat` file from a **program called Polyglot Tolerant**, it is called as **Polyglot Chess-book.** This program can be found in the below link along with a small README file explaining the simple process:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZQkN2mQwMiLrCoMCpRlGMY-Zq9UrWVmF?usp=sharing

**Main Question:** I am able to make chess-books in `.bin` format from `.pgn` files. But the problem is I am only able to make one book at a time. When I have to **convert 2000+ distinct** `.pgn` files named say `database1.pgn`, `games.pgn`, `tournament.pgn`, etc. to distinct `.bin` format book files with same names like `database1.bin`, `games.bin`, `tournament.bin`, etc. respectively, then I do not know a way as how to do this.

How can we **batch convert** `.pgn` files to `.bin` format in Ubuntu 20.10?

Comment: Have you tried to use [`pgn-extract` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/pgn-extract)? Or maybe [some binaries](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/scid/filelist) from `scid` package?

Comment: Yes. I have used both these software. The can both be used together for conversion from .pgn to .bin. A simpler program for this specific task is Polyglot Tolerant. But we can only convert one single file at a time. I wish to convert several distinct files generating multiple .bin files in one operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Polyglot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man6/polyglot.6.html) might be what you want.

Install it like so:

```
sudo apt install polyglot
```

And use it like so:

```
for f in *.pgn
    do
    f1="${f%.pgn}"
    polyglot make-book -pgn "$f" -bin "$f1".bin -min-game 1
    done
```

**Run the above code from within the directory containing the `.pgn` files.**

Comment: You are a magician for me. Success. I succeeded in converting every .pgn file to .bin file with your answer. Thank you very much. It will help a lot of Chess players. Many thanks. :) I will save the above command. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to run the same command on many files to convert them from one format to another. I couldn't easily figure out the command you're running so I replaced it with `pgn_to_bin` below and I assume it outputs its result to the console (`stdout`).

Run this in the (Bash) shell/terminal in the directory containing your `.pgn` files:

```
for file in *.pgn; do
    pgn_to_bin "${file}" > "${file%.pgn}.bin"
done
```

Translated to English, this is: for each filename in the current directory ending with `.png`, do this:

- `pgn_to_bin filename_with_pgn_extension > filename_without_pgn_extension.bin`

If you have the files `file1.pgn` and `file2.pgn`, this will execute:

```
pgn_to_bin "file1.pgn" > "file1.bin"
pgn_to_bin "file2.pgn" > "file2.bin"
```

Now you just have to adjust the command line to match the current process you use to convert a single file.

Btw, the `${file%.pgn}` syntax uses [Bash's parameter substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the `.pgn` suffix from the input filename.